# How to get text and respond to enter press on JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jformattedtextfield

I recently added a `MaskFormatter` to my `JFormattedTextField` class. Previously an `ActionListener` was responding to the code and getting the text using the `.getText()` method worked fine. With the new `MaskFormatter` getting the text returns "   " and enter presses don't work (the `ActionListener` stopped responding to the box).

Here is the entire JFormattedTextField class:

```
package swing;

import game.Main;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
import window.Listener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextField extends JFormattedTextField
    {
    public TextField(int size, String text) 
       //TODO limit to number input and 3 character input only
    {
        super(createFormatter());

        Font font = new Font("AGENCY FB", Font.BOLD, 30);

        this.setFont(font);
        this.setColumns(size);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        this.setText(text);
    }

    private static MaskFormatter createFormatter()
    {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try 
        {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter("###");
        } 
        catch (java.text.ParseException exc) 
        {
            System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return formatter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type 3 digits and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it works for me.

```
public class FieldAction extends JFrame {

    FieldAction() {

        MaskFormatter mask = null;
        try {
            mask = new MaskFormatter("###");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println(textField.getText());
            }
        });

        add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new FieldAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: A FieldAction? Where abouts would I call this from?

Comment: @Roboguy99 Type 123 and press Enter. If it doesn't print `123` check to see if your console works.

Comment: @Roboguy99 Just copy-paste this into a separate file and run it. The class name is arbitrary, name it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code below can work for you. This way, whenever you press an enter, you will be able to see the inputted text.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                 System.out.println(this.getText().trim());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener`s for this, `ActionListener` is the correct way,

Comment: This gives me "The method getText() is undefined for the type new KeyAdapter(){}"